# Dinamically loaded .js file is not being cached. Why might that be?

Tags: javascript, caching, asynchronous

I have a javascript function (lets call it "loadScript"), binded to the click of a button. Inside that "loadScript", I run the following code:

```
if (typeof object == 'undefined') {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "/js/myscript.js";
    script.onload = function () {
        console.log("Script just loaded!");
    };
    document.head.appendChild(script);
} else {
    console.log("Script already available");
}
```

Notice, "object" is a javascript object located inside myscript.js file, and I test for its existence in order to know if the script is available to use or not.

So first time I click the button, script gets loaded, everything works as expected, second time I click the button script is available already, so no loading occurs.
Now if I browse away to another page (on the same site and app) and inmediatly come back to Page 1, clicking the button loads the script again! Like it is not cached or something.

I have also tried **$.getScript** as well as its full version using **$.ajax({cache: true})** and even set **$.ajaxSetup({cache: true})** globally.
None solved this issue.

*UPDATE 01*

I also tried puting the `script` element directly inside the `head` of my page, and added an `async` attribute to it so the user doesn't have to wait for the whole thing in order to view the page. The result: the script **does not cache** either.

Only after I remove the `async` attribute it becomes "cacheable" but hey, the whole point of this question is to load the script dinamically and keep it cached, like a normal external asset would!

Comment: what browser are you using? :)

Comment: try doing `curl -I example.com/js/myscript.js` to see if there is a header preventing caching.

Comment: @SushilBastola Chrome 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64 bits) ;)

Comment: @styfle sure thing! this is the result https://pastebin.com/raw/EZj8JK8w

Comment: When you navigate away from the page, then back again, the html is the same as the first time you viewed the page and script tag is not in the page, so must load again. The "script is already available" will never output on the first click of the button after the page is loaded, even if you have visited it before. The actual loading should be loaded by cache though. What makes you think it is not loading from cache? Did you check chrome dev tools to see if it is loaded from cache?

Comment: @2pha I am glued to Chrome Dev Tools, their filters and Throttle options really helped me understand that the script is actually loading everytime I re-enter the page and click the button. It takes 5 seconds to load every single time.

Comment: There's a typo. Change `script.src = "/js/myscript.js' />";` to `script.src = '/js/myscript.js';`

Comment: @styfle Thanks for pointing that out, it was actually a residue of my original code after I adapated it for correct StackOverflow presentation